# Tile a seamless texture

Tags: texturing, uv-image-editor

I'm trying to create a wire mesh using a plane and a png texture but when I scale up the UV map in the UV editor this happens. [image]

Does anyone know how to tile the texture across the whole plane?
I'm using version 2.82

Comment: could you try using a mapping node instead of scaling the UV?